# String.prototype.split() return a strange array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to find out what is the value of `empty` which is contructed by `"".split("\n")`.
Here is my trial of finding it.

```js
var empty = "";
empty = empty.split("\n");
console.log("Is empty's length one? ")
console.log(empty.length === 1);
console.log("------");
console.log("Is empty's first value is a empty string (\"\")? ");
console.log(empty[0] === "");
console.log("------");
console.log("Then what is the constructor of empty? ");
console.log(empty.constructor.name);
console.log("------");
console.log("Is empty === [\"\"]? ");
console.log(empty === [""]);
console.log("------");
console.log("Is empty == [\"\"]? ");
console.log(empty == [""]);
console.log("------");
console.log("Then what is empty? ");
console.log(empty);
```

As you see, empty has the length one and the value of it is an empty string.
The question is, why it isn't equal to `[""]` and what is the value of it?

Comment: This doesn't work because that's not how equality comparison with arrays works.

Comment: You could have reduced that simply to `[''] == ['']`… (which is `false`)

Comment: Because `[]` is an object, they will be compared by reference, not by value.